# Xml response file: Received in browser, not via C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, webexception

I'm trying to access the last.fm APIs via C#. As a first test I'm querying similar artists if that matters.

I get an XML response when I pass a correct artist name, i.e. "Nirvana". My problem is when I deliver an invalid name (i.e. "Nirvana23") I don't receive XML but an error code (403 or 400) and a `WebException`.

Interesting thing: If I enter the URL inside a browser (tested with Firefox and Chrome) I receive the XML file I want (containing a lastfm specific error message).

I tried both `XmlReader` and `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(requestUrl);
```

and `HttpWebRequest`:

```
string httpResponse = "";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

HttpWebResponse response = null;
StreamReader reader = null;

try
{
     response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
     httpResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The URL is something like "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=Nirvana23" (and a specific key given by lastfm, but even without it - it should return XML). A link to give it a try: [link](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=Nirvana23) (this is the error file I cannot access via C#).

What I also tried (without success): comparing the request by both the browser and my program with the help of WireShark. Then I added some headers to the request, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I haven't used WireShark, but you might have better luck with an HTTP debugger, like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET the WebRequest is converting HTTP error codes into exceptions, while your browser is just ignoring them since the response is not empty. If you catch the exception then the GetResponseStream method should still return the error XML that you are expecting.

Edit:

Try this:

```
string httpResponse = "";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);

WebResponse response = null;
StreamReader reader = null;
try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    response = ex.Response;
}

reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
httpResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The problem is that the exception is thrown by the request.GetResponse() method. So the stream isn't really readable. Anyway, I tried to put the StreamReader lines in a catch block but I just get unreadable stuff.  
  
  
`   catch (WebException e)
    {
         response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
         reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
         httpResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }`

Comment: Added an example. You will probably want to look at the error code in the WebException, and handle the response accordingly instead of just blindly returning the response from the exception.

Comment: I tried that but, unfortunately, the StreamReader can't read something useful. There are only useless escape and special characters. I suppose the WebException does not offer what I want - an XML file like this one I get if I open the folloewing link in a browser [link](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=Nirvana23).

Comment: I don't know why but I tried it again today and it worked! (Maybe lastfm has changed something on the server side or I made the same mistake yesterday over and over again.)
Anyway, now it works. Thanks!
Small side note: the response in the try and catch blocks has to be casted to HttWebResponse.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you catch the exception and then process that accordingly. If you want to display any custom error, you can do that also in your catch block.

Comment: With that, I would not know what exactly made the problem. Lastfm delivers an XML file with specific information about the error (e.g. wrong authentification key or unknown artist). This file is what I like to evaluate.

Comment: Did you checked what is the status code for invalid artist and for wrong authentication? If we see they are different then catching that error and then based on the status code we can identify what went wrong.

Comment: Maybe I didn't point this out clearly, but what I want to get (and what I get in a browser) is an XML file which contains information about the error. Opening [link](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=Nirvana23) in a browser delivers this XML file I want. So this is not a HTTP error code.